# not a mach-o file

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

My code doesn't seem to be able to find a specific file I created. The `.so` file is in the same folder as the `.py` file named `super_real_time_massive.so.` I get the following error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/sebastianvolkl/Desktop/Ildaron_EEGwithRaspberryPI_master_GUI/super_real_time_massive.so, 0x0006): tried: 
'/Users/sebastianvolkl/Desktop/Ildaron_EEGwithRaspberryPI_master_GUI/super_real_time_massive.so' 
(not a mach-o file), '/usr/lib/super_real_time_massive.so' (no such file)
```

This is the part of the code I'm trying to run:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
libc = ctypes.CDLL("/Users/sebastianvolkl/Desktop/Ildaron_EEGwithRaspberryPI_master_GUI/super_real_time_massive.so")
libc.prepare()
```

Here you can see that the file is in the folder

```
sebastianvolkl@bastimacbook Ildaron_EEGwithRaspberryPI_master_GUI % ls
Makefile            real_time_massive.c
ReadMe.txt          real_time_massive.h
libperiphery.a          real_time_without_thread.py
real_time.py            super_real_time_massive.so
```

Comment: Read the error again. It says `(not a mach-o file)`, so it looks like it's trying to fall back to `/usr/lib`. To check what filetype it actually is, try running `file super_real_time_massive.so`. But I'm not an expert on this. You might want to add some tags related to the libraries and systems you're using to attract actual experts.

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the contents of the *Makefile*, the full (*Python*) code (might want to save it in a script in order to easy run it multiple times) and its output.